# Call array storing string type from one while to another

Tags: c++, arrays

How to fix the code? I can't use vectors. I need to be able to call the names for the courses from the first while to the second one and display them.

```
cout << "Please enter the number of classes"<< endl;//Number of classes for the while
    cin >> nclass;
while (count <= nclass ) // while
{
    //Information for the class
    {
        cout << "Please enter the course name for the class # "<< count << endl;
            getline (cin, name);
        string name;
        string coursename[nclass];
        for (int i = 0; i < nclass; i++) {
            coursename[i] = name;
        }
    }

    char choose;
    cin >> choose;
    while ( choose == 'B' || choose == 'b') {//Name the courses
        for (int x = 0; x < nclass; x++){
            cout << "Here is a list of all the courses: \n" << coursename[i] << endl;
        }
        return 0 ;
    }
```

Comment: the problem inside your loop

Comment: `string coursename[nclass];` non standard C++. Don't be surprised if this does not compile on the marker's PC.

Comment: @user4581301 on linux it's ok

Comment: *string coursename[nclass];* -- You say you can't use vectors, yet you use something that isn't valid C++.  Also, the way you get around that syntax *is* to use `std::vector`.

Comment: @Raindrop7 -- Linux is an operating system, not a C++ compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know I mean Gcc for example

Comment: Doesn't matter -- it isn't valid C++, and the requirements that vectors cannot be used flies in the face of making any sense if invalid C++ syntax can be used.

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear".  The reason being that you state requirements of what you can't use (vector), yet you're using something that isn't valid C++ (variable length arrays).  So you need to clarify **exactly** what you can and cannot use.

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring coursename as local inside loop and then using it outside so you get a compile time error (coursename is undeclared identifier).

one question: what is the role of inner for-loop????!!!

you use a for loop inside while loop through which you are assigning all the elements the same value as the string name has!!!
so every time count increments the inner for loop assigns the new value of name after being assigned, to the all elements of coursename.

count is undefined! so declare it and initialize it to 1 or 0 and take this in mind.

you wrote to the outbounds of coursname: count <= nclss to correct it:

```
while(count < nclass)...
```

another important thing: clear the input buffer to make cin ready for the next input. with cin.ignore or sin.sync

```
cout << "Please enter the number of classes"<< endl;//Number of classes for the while
cin >> nclass;
string coursename[nclass];
int count = 0;

while (count < nclass ) // while
{
    //Information for the class
    string name;
    cout << "Please enter the course name for the class # "<< count << endl;

    cin.ignore(1, '\n');
    getline (cin, name);
    coursename[count] = name;
    cin.ignore(1, '\n');
    count++;
}

char choose;
cin >> choose;
while ( choose == 'B' || choose == 'b') {//Name the courses
    for (int x = 0; x < nclass; x++){
        cout << "Here is a list of all the courses: \n" << coursename[x] << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Bit of a danger point here: `cin.ignore(1, '\n');` Immediately after a getline, this should eat the first character of the next line. Useful for eating an empty line, but destructive to everything else.

Comment: With the suggestions made I get the last course name entered repeated by the number of classes.
else if (choice == 'B' || choice == 'b') {//List all courses
                                cout << "Here is a list of all the courses: \n";
                                        for (int x = 0; x < nclass; x++){
                                        cout << coursename [x] << endl;
                        }
                        return 0 ;
                }

Answer (score -1):

This code works!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int nclass = 0, count = 1, countn = 1;
    string name[100];
    cout << "Please enter the number of classes" << endl;
    cin >> nclass;

   while (count <= nclass) {
      cout << "Please enter the course name for the class # " << count << endl;
      cin >> name[count];
      count++;
      }

    cout << "Here is a list of all the courses: " << endl;
    while (countn <= nclass) {
        cout << name[countn] << endl;
       countn++;
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that gave the array "name" the size of 100. Nobody is going to have 100 classes! There is no need for the for loops. It is a good practice to initialize the count and the new count which is designated by countn. Why is my answer voted down when it works?

Comment: Recommend some explanation. Code only answers get cut-n-pasted into homework assignments and graduate [Cargo Cult Programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) I have to waste time on weeding out of the hiring pool.